# When to use the trait Instance() constructor, and questions about the traitsUI tutorial code

Tags: traits, enthought, traitsui

I have a question regarding the [traitsui tutorial](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html) by Gael Varoquaux.
In code snippet 7 he makes a CaptureThread class for producing a thread for taking images from a camera. He also make a Camera class.

```
class TextDisplay(HasTraits):
    string = String()
    view = View(Item('string', show_label=False, springy=True, style='custom'))

class CaptureThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        #self.display is set outside the class definition by the caller
        self.display.string = 'Camera started\n' + self.display.string
        n_img = 0
        while not self.wants_abort:
            sleep(0.5)
            n_img += 1
            self.display.string = ' %d image captured\n' % n_img \
                                        + self.display.string
        self.display.string = 'Camera stopped\n' + self.display.string

class Camera(HasTraits):
    start_stop_capture = Button()
    display = Instance(TextDisplay)
    capture_thread = Instance(CaptureThread)

    view = View( Item('start_stop_capture', show_label=False))

    def _start_stop_capture_fired(self):
        if self.capture_thread and self.capture_thread.isAlive():
            self.capture_thread.wants_abort = True
        else:
            self.capture_thread = CaptureThread()
            self.capture_thread.wants_abort = False
            self.capture_thread.display = self.display
            self.capture_thread.start()
```

I have two questions about this code:

1) Why in the Camera class definition does he make capture_thread a Trait, by calling Instance(CaptureThread)? CaptureThread is just a thread class, why should we make a trait instance out of it?

2) In the CaptureThread class he makes use of a field self.display.string and of self.wants_abort. These two fields are not passed in via a constructor method, rather they are assigned outside of the class definition by the Camera class. Is this the best practise? Since if the user of the CaptureThread forgot to set these two fields, then an error would occur. Are there some sensible guidelines to know when I can assign thing like that, or I should use a constructor to assign them?

I hope that these questions make sense, and that this is the right place to ask them!
Thanks, labjunky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `capture_thread = Instance(CaptureThread)` doesn't make an instance of `CaptureThread`. It is more of a declaration that gets consumed by the `Camera` class when the class gets created. It tells that `Camera` class that it will have an attribute named `capture_thread` that should be an instance of `CaptureThread` or `None` and will default to `None`. This default lets the "test if `self.capture_thread` is initialized, otherwise create it" logic in `_start_stop_capture_fired()` a little cleaner, at least to some people's tastes.
2. For `threading.Thread` subclasses, yes, it's one idiomatic way to do it, though not the only one. `Thread` already has a specific [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading#threading.Thread) implementation, and you *could* override it to do something else, but it is understandable that the author would avoid doing so in this case.

   This is *not* the idiomatic way to initialize `HasTraits` subclasses which is indeed to use keyword arguments.